# Visual Studio Code and PowerShell do not identify new Python version

Tags: python, powershell, visual-studio-code, path

On Windows 10, I want to use Python 3.8, which I installed and downloaded.

However, in Visual Studio Code, the `cmd`-environment, and PowerShell, the command `python` returns 3.5.6, an Anaconda install.

In particular, the screenshot shows that (at the bottom left) the active interpreter should be 3.8.1; and the "Python Path" in the settings also directs to the correct path, but typing `python` in Terminal just outputs 3.5.6.

[image: VS Code Screenshot]

In the `PATH`-variable, I deleted the line that points to 3.5.6's directory, and added the directory of 3.8.1 (was done automatically during the install):

[image]

**What more do I need to do?**

---

### Edit 1

Environment Variables are:

**Path:** C:\Users\d91776\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\d91776\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\java\jdk\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin;C:\Users\d91776\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\d91776\Desktop\Selenium Markitwire\geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64;C:\Users\d91776\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;

**PSModulePath:** %HomeDrive%%HomePath%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Users\d91776\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\PowerShell

**TEMP** and **TMP:** are both %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp

There is another "Path" in System variables, but I cannot display it as text. But it does not seem to related to the python paths. See highlighted section in Screenshot:

[image]

---

### Edit 2

In Anaconda, I deactivated the one additional environment that had Python version 3.5.6.

However, the problem now persists with Python version 3.7.3 (version of Python displayed upon typing `python` in terminal) and 3.8.1 (selected in VS Code as Python interpreter, and displayed in the bottom-left, just as in the above screenshot).

```
C:\>python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: Have you tried to reboot you system? I got an other problem where the PATH only will be updated when the system is rebooted.

Comment: yes, multiple times, the problem persists for all three terminals.

Comment: Can you put all your environment variables? System and user please? Just to check that don't forget anyone

Comment: I did it and edited the question.

Comment: hope it will help you : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: I referred to that site to change the Python Path. However, the site does not mention a possible discrepancy between the python version shown in the bottom-left of VS Code and the python version used in Terminal. This is the content of my file `settings.json`: `{
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\d91776\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python.exe"
}`

Answer (score 1):

The Python extension for VS Code does not influence what the `python` command points at; that comes down to your `PATH` environment variable. If you want to manually launch Python 3.8 then you should run `python3.8` or `py -3.8` (if you just want the newest Python 3 installed then change that to `python3` or `py -3`). Otherwise create a virtual environment with Python 3.8 and when it's activated `python` will be Python 3.8.

As for why this doesn't work in PowerShell, it's possible the install of Python 3.8 that you used installed a `python` command for Python 3.8 (you would have to check those directories on your `PATH` to verify this).